# How to edit properties of hdfs-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I want to modify a property `dfs.namenode.replication.work.multiplier.per.iteration` in hdfs-default.xml. I couldn't locate hdfs-default.xml and I tried finding this property in hdfs-site.xml. I couldn't find it. Please help where and how to change this property.

Comment: It is a advanced property. It is not recommended to change it. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: @ManjunathBallur : I need to improve the performance while decommissioning of a host from the cluster.

Comment: You can just add this property to hdfs-site.xml

Comment: @ManjunathBallur : Thank you Manjunath. Do I need to restart hadoop? Will this change affect the performance?

Comment: I guess, you need restart. I am not sure about the performance part. I have never tried this before.